# How to focus on some items?

Tags: beamer, itemize

I have 3 items in beamer as follows:

```
\frame{\frametitle{Frame1}
     \begin{itemize}
          \item<1> Self-X1, $\cdots$.
          \item<2, 4-> \color<4>{red}{Self-X2}, $\cdots$.
          \item<3> Self-X3, $\cdots$.
\end{itemize}
}
```

However, I did not succeed to get what I want.

I would like to show the three items at once. Then, I would like to focus only on the second item and make its color red. (The first and third item should become visible but faded (transparent).)

How can I do this please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this? You can apply the overlay option to the whole document or remove it after the item list.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
 %\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\begin{document}

\frame{\frametitle{Frame1}
 \setbeamercovered{transparent}
     \begin{itemize}
          \item<1-1> Self-X1, $\cdots$.
          \item<1-2> \alert<2>{Self-X2} $\cdots$.
          \item<1-1> Self-X3, $\cdots$.
\end{itemize}
 %\setbeamercovered{transparent}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Side note: OP should rather use the `alert` style here. `\alert<2>{Self-X2}`